# Is there any way to manually remove a remote as my git lfs contains more than one remote

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-lfs

i have created a repo with lfs installed, but another collaborator also called git lfs install command which after pushing to master caused an issue where now when i am trying to call git lfs pull it says the lfs url contains more than one remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so figured it out
in the .git folder in the local repo folder there is a file .gitconfig there you can set all the git lfs urls